# ajax not showing anything

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $.ajax({url: "demo_test.txt",  async: true,success: function(result){
      $("#div1").html(result);
    }});
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="div1"><h2>Let jQuery AJAX Change This Text</h2></div>

<button>Get External Content</button>



</body>
</html>
```

this is the code which i want to describe here.
when i click on button ajax call is not happening.
no errors in console.
please help

Comment: Have a look  at the browser console for possible errors

Comment: I cannot [reproduce this on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/philbrown/d5ea73sf/3/) (using their `/echo/html` service to simulate your `demo_test.txt`). The only possible problem is if your `demo_test.txt` file is not where you think it is or you're using the `file:///` protocol to open your page

Comment: does it even show alert when you put it inside your click event? if yes, try to put it inside your success function call. also check your file exists and is accessible